# How can I optimize a formula on data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, data-science, mathematical-optimization

I have an analytically derrived formula that looks something like this;
**y = ((b/x)^n )* e^(-c(x-b)) * D** 
[image]

In the formula x is my independent variable. Alle the other lettres on the right side of the equation are parameters that I want to estimate.

I have a dataset with y and x. Is there a way by which I can get the most optimal values of the parameters b,c,d and n that minimizes square error of y.

I also have alot of constraints, such as b being inbetween 0 and 10, and c being inbetween 0 and 0.5 etc.

Is there way I can perform such an optimization problem in R preferrably? And furthermore, is it possible to have parameters b,c and d predicted by other variables in my dataset. This then becomes more of a ML problem, but I want the model to be written in the same way as the first mentioned formula.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at nls (Nonlinear Least Squares): https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/nls. You give it a formula and data and you can define constraints with the control parameter.

Comment: It might be useful to log-transform the equation first: `ln y = n ln B + ln D - C(x - B) - n ln x`, which makes the (natural) log of `y` a superposition of a linear and logarithmic function in `x`.